# Drupal6: Trying to get errors from node_validate()

Tags: php, validation, drupal, drupal-6

I'm trying to validate a set of nodes before saving them to the database:

```
foreach ($nodes_to_save as $node) {
    if (! (node_validate($node, $form))) {
        form_set_error('', t('Node %title did not validate. No nodes were saved.', array('%title' => $node->title)));
        $success = FALSE;
        break;
    }
}
```

The documentation for [node_validate](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_validate/7) says that it will call `form_set_error()` to indicate why the node hasn't validated. However, this does not happen with the above code. All I get is the error I set manually. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this 
the `$form` should be an array !

```
foreach ($nodes_to_save as $node) 
{
    if (! (node_validate($node, $form))) 
    {
        form_set_error('', t('Node %title did not validate. No nodes were saved.', &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__));
        $success = FALSE;
        return $success;
    }
}
```

Or dont use the if beause `node_validate doesnt` `return true` or `false`;

```
foreach ($nodes_to_save as $node) 
{
       node_validate($node, $form);
        $success = FALSE;
        return $success;
    }
}
```

note that node_validate takes as first parameter an object and as second parameter an array

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this be more useful?

```
$success = true;
foreach ($nodes_to_save as $node){
    node_validate($node);
    //returns null or array
    $errors = form_get_errors();
    //if there was an error, send an extra message indicating the node that was not saved
    if($errors){
        form_set_error('', t('Node %title did not validate. It was not saved.', array('%title' => $node->title)));
        $success = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Instead of returning `$success` as `FALSE` for every single node that is run through the loop?